# Is the universe a perpetual motion machine?

Tags: cosmology, universe, perpetual-motion

Is the universe a perpetual motion machine?

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: Some comments were deleted/censored. Please keep the language civil.

Comment: Hey cool it guys. I ask myself questions as ill-posed as the OP's all the time: maybe he/she could have thought more about it, maybe not and found the concept too bewildering. As onlookers we are in no position to judge. [Kleingordon has given a wonderful answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/103525/26076) that illustrates how working out how to ask the ill-posed questions is a highly nontrivial part of the scientific method. How we bring meaning to "perpetual motion" when in general there is no cosmological global definition of time and thus no conservation of energy is an ...

Comment: ...  excellent question and one that [Kleingordon](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/103525/26076) shows we can still answer precisely. There has been some wonderful physics illustrated here as a result of the OP's question that I have thoroughly enjoyed seeing.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance, philosophically, the question is meaningless; the Universe is simply *all there is, was and will be* - **including the laws of physics**.  The laws of physics are not apart from or independent of the Universe.  The Universe - *Existence* - **exists**.  There are no laws that govern Existence for that would imply something outside, independent of, and apart from *Existence*.  The notion of *perpetual motion*, in any form, has no meaning independent of the context of *Existence*.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I don't quite see what you're getting at: Kleingordon's answers seem to be within the physically observable. You make a valid point that one can't go outside the Universe to find meaning, which is one way wherein the OP's question is ill posed. But I think Kleingordon counters by showing that we can pull back so that we're thinking within physical existence and still have meaningful fragments. Perhaps you should add to Kleingordon's last sentence: it is the reason why one can't extend the wonted idea of "perpetual motion" to the heat-dead universe. Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance, what I'm trying to get at is that the concept "Universe" refers to all of existence, leaving out nothing and thus, is not something *within* Existence, such as a *machine* which is necessarily subject to physical law.  The Universe isn't an existent or an entity.  Kleingordon's answer is fine in that it addresses possibly the only possible coherent interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, not if you use the standard definition for "[perpetual motion machines of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion)", which can indefinitely produce work. Entropy increases monotonically over the entire universe, and eventually all [free energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_free_energy) will be gone. This is known as [heat death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe).

Will particles in the universe continue moving forever? Probably. But that's not what perpetual motion thought experiments are typically about.

Comment: A fantastic answer bringing precise meaning to a slightly wobbly question: I ask myself questions as ill-posed as the OP's all the time, and the way that you have worked out how to ask the question and answer it so clearly is a wonderful illustration of the theoretical scientific method.

Comment: You're very welcome. This is one of the many reasons I've come to adore Physics SE.

Comment: Couldn't the universe be infinitely large with infinite matter?  So are you assuming the Universe is curved?

Comment: This answer doesn't allow for the possibility of "infinite divisibility", described in Wikipedia:  However, it would only work in a universe or multiverse that would be spatially infinite, and temporally eternal both to the past and to the future.  Cosmological models compatible with it include Aguirre & Gratton's "Steady-state eternal inflation", Nikodem Poplawski's "Cosmology with torsion", and 2020 Nobel Prize winner Roger Penrose's "Conformal cyclic cosmology", whose preprints can be found by their names on Arxiv.  Their eternality's discussed in Lindford's "Big bounce or double bang?".